# How can I make this cool chocolate shape?

Tags: chocolate

I've fallen in love with [this picture](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/309563_371607769602871_2011678230_n.jpg).

[image]

I am wondering how I can make the white chocolate layer.

My guesses are:

- option A: use a bottle and "pour" melted white chocolate above it
  -- downside: ? the chocolate wouldn't get nice and smooth as in the picture.
- option B: use a 2 pieces plastic moulder(like when making Eastern eggs) and "pour" white chocolate above it. Once poured use a different but smaller plastic shell and place it in the moulder in order to flat the chocolate.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it is more likely that the pastry chef employed a piece of [food grade acetate](http://www.countrykitchensa.com/shop/candy-making-supplies/acetate-sheets/39/582/616/629475/) (the link is a sample vendor).

They would have piped the pattern of tempered white chocolate onto the acetate sheet, then rolled it into a cylinder (chocolate on the inside) taping or clamping it shut to set.  Once thoroughly chilled, they would have very, very carefully peeled the sheet from the chocolate.

This is a very advanced technique, especially with white chocolate, which is persnickety and tough to temper, and often not as solid as dark chocolate.  Good luck.

Comment: thanks (also for the edit). How do you get the cylinder away/out from the chocolate once you remove the acetate? One way I can think of is to have a food grade acetate also outside the cylinder . The other is to place some wipe dipped in hot water in the "inner" part of the cylinder (not in contact with the chocolate) to heat it slightly and allow the "chef" to remove it from the chocolate.

Comment: PS: I thought that is possible to substitue the acetate with a good "baking paper sheet". Is this asking too much to the "poor" paper :)?

Comment: I am not an expert chocolatier, but to the best of my understanding, you roll the chocolate on the inside of the acetate when rolled.  There is no other mold or form, just the acetate.  Note that the picture shows the smooth surface on the *outside*.  The acetate is *very* smooth and will release from well chilled and properly temperated chocolate.  That is why chocolatiers use it.

Comment: My guess is that even parchment will be too "sticky" for this technique.

Comment: Thanks :). I will give it a proper go. Really want to make it :), is just an amazing technique to master that can unleash a lot of creative freedom in desserts making :)

Comment: I've used parchment paper and it works up to a certain level. For basic designs it's fine.

Comment: personally I would not use parchment as it is very unstable. I would pipe the tempered chocolate on to the acetate, which should be pre-cut into the necessary shape, allow it to set every so slightly and then roll it. because the acetate is stiffer than parchment it will stay in a cylindrical shape

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the chef used a blown up, tube shaped balloon, like for making balloon animals. After drizzling the chocolate and allowing it to harden, he popped the balloon. I tend to suspect that this is actually correct, because a similar technique is used for making chocolate bowls.

Comment: While possible, wouldn't a thin layer of chocolate like this break when the balloon pops? For the bowls you usually have a thicker layer of chocolate I think.

Comment: I'm curious enough to try it!  I'll post pictures if it works. If it doesn't work, I'll cop to it :)